# Can I show this using a contraction semigroup property?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $H$ be a (real) Hilbert space, $L$ be an unbounded operator on $H$ with its domain $D(L)$ and $(e^{-tL})_{t\ge 0}$ be a contraction semigroup on $H$.

Then, the following holds from a semigroup property?

$$(Lh_0, h_0) \le \kappa (h_0, h_0) \Longrightarrow (Le^{-tL}h_0, e^{-tL}h_0) \le \kappa (e^{-tL}h_0, e^{-tL}h_0), \quad \text{ for }\,\forall h_0 \in D(L)$$

where $(\,\,,\,)$ is an inner product on $H$.

I'd appreciate it if you'd give me any advice.

Comment: Should the the implication be of the form $(\forall h \dots\implies\forall h\dots)$ or $\forall h(\dots\implies \dots)$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The latter it is! I will add it to the post.

Comment: $(Lh_0,h_0)\le \kappa (h_0,h_0)$ for all $h_0\in\mathcal{D}(L)$ allows you to replace $h_0$ with $e^{-tL}h_0$, because $e^{-tL}h_0\in\mathcal{D}(L)$.

Answer (score 0):

If the operator $L$ generates a contraction semigroup on $H$, then
$$(L h_0, h_0) \le 0 \le \kappa \|h_0\|^2, \quad \forall h_0 \in D(L),$$
where $\kappa$ is any **nonnegative** real number. It suffices to apply the above inequality for $h_0'=e^{-tL}h_0$ where $h_0 \in D(L)$.